# javax.persistence.PersistenceException - JPA+Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, nhibernate-mapping, jta

I am new to JPA, when I tried to run the following code, it showing error as "**cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.**"

I cant able to fix this error, could u pls help me out to solve this issue.

Cheers

Rajesh

### Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="jpa" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.optirisk.pojo.Department</class>
        <class>com.optirisk.pojo.Employee</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="NewsLetter1" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="optiindia2012" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/orpss_hibernate_prototype" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### Application.java

```
public class Application {

    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "jpa";
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

        Department department = new Department();
        department.setDeptName("IT");
        entityManager.persist(department);

        Employee emp1 = new Employee("Peter", "ROB", "454565");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("Mathew", "Anderson", "222");

        emp1.setDepartment(department);
        emp2.setDepartment(department);

        entityManager.persist(emp1);
        entityManager.persist(emp2);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManager.close();

    }

}
```

### Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    at com.jishraa.jpa.Application.main(Application.java:19)
```

Answer (score 10):

The issue is a mismatch between your <persistence version="2.1"...> and your hibernate library requirements.  Copy and paste the whole persistence tag with name spaces (xmlns) from a reliable sample.  Then check your library version, below.

From hibernate.org: http://hibernate.org/orm/downloads/

> Supported JPA Versions
>
> ```
> JPA 1.0: ORM 3.2+
> JPA 2.0: ORM 3.5+
> JPA 2.1: ORM 4.3+
> ```
>
> Note that newer ORM releases are backwards compatible with older JPA
>   versions (ex: ORM 4.3 with JPA 1.0). However, newer ORM releases may
>   not be compatible with older JPA containers.

The JPA version is the same as the persistence version.  The ORM is the version of hibernate.  So your persistence file has `<persistence version="2.1" ... >`. So, as of now,  you want only the hibernate library and version below (or a later version):

```
WEB-INF/lib/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar
```

or Maven pom.xml:

```
<!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I spent a whole bunch of hours on this one.  I hope my time spent saves yours!

Answer (score 4):

I suspect your environment only supports persistence 2.0.  Try changing:

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
```

To:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn Lane, after changing the version it take me to another kind of error called "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class "

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `<persistence>` element in your xml... check the xsd you posted and make your persistence.xml comply to the schema. See [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/task_manage_persistence.htm) for a simple example