# Hibernate configuration in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I installed the Hibernate plug-in on Eclipse from [here](http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/luna/).

Installation is successful-- I'm now seeing `Hibernate` as an option in `Window > Open Perspective`.

I've set the properties on the project itself-- `Enable Hibernate support` is now checked in `Properties > Hibernate Settings`. 
Also, `Hibernate Builder` is checked (was automatically) in `Properties Builders`.

However, Java is not seeing Hibernate-- I'm getting errors to all Hibernate imports in my source code. 
When I attempt to "Fix project setup..." in the editor, I get "No proposals found ... click for manual configuration."

What am i missing?

I downloaded Hibernate plug-in to get around this manual fix for one thing. The same code is working all fine when I manually add the jars to the project build path.

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2

TIA.

//-------------------------

EDIT:

While autocreating `persistence.xml`, Eclipse is (must be) looking at the version of Hibernate plug-in, not the jars on the project's build-path.

And that's causing a version conflict in between JPA and ORM. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176545/javax-persistence-persistenceexception-jpahibernate) for reference.

Burned me half a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug-ins make *Eclipse* Hibernate-aware, not necessarily your *project*. Your project still must be configured (either manually or via a dependency management tool like Maven or Gradle) with the appropriate Hibernate JARs. It's the difference between development-time (the Eclipse plug-ins), compile-time (JARs on the build path) and runtime (JARs on the runtime classpath).

It would be nice if the plug-in provided a Quick Fix (à la *Fix project setup...*) that offered to download and/or add Hibernate JARs to your project, but as far as I know that's not something they implemented.

Comment: so, what did enabling Hibernate support and Hibernate builder on the project do?

Comment: It enabled all kinds of nice tooling, features listed at http://hibernate.org/tools/